# Ambari 2.2.1 restart services

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

After installing `Hortonworks sandbox 2.4` I can not find out how to restart service like `hbase` `Hdfs` from `Ambari`.
So what I need to know how to restart `hadoop` services from `Ambari` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SandBox 2.4` you have to reset the username and the password for the user `Admin`
I think you are logging in as `maria_dev` where this user have the `read-only` permission, if this is the case,

what you need to do is lancing the script `ambari-admin-password-reset` , enter username and a password for the user admin and login by this user.